# Getting getters (or methods or properties) list in generic class with Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I can't figure out how should i deal with generics in kotlin.

I'm writing a history class for changes made on generic objects, which should get any type of class as parameter: after that, I would compare the old object values with the new object values, and if I found a difference, I'll write that in my data class.

I've succedeed doing that with java with `bean.getClass().getMethods();`, but I want to trying move to Kotlin.

```
class ChangeHistoryUtils<T> (val originalBean : T, username : String , var modifiedBean: T? = null) {

    data class ChangeHistory(val username: String, val fieldName : String,
                    val oldValue : String , val newValue : String , val date : LocalDate = LocalDate.now())

    fun compareBeans(){
        //how to get all originalBean getters and its values?
    }
}
```

I'm actually stuck here: how should obtain all the getters in my `T` object?

Let's guess i'll receive a class which with 10 getters, I want to call all these 10 getters in `originalBean`, and comparing its value with the ones in `modifiedBean`. If different, I will write it in my `ChangeHistory`

Thanks

Comment: how did you solve it in Java? Most probably a similar approach will work in Kotlin too...

Comment: I've added that to question: but there's nothing similar in kotlin with similar syntax. If I type `originalBean.` the compiler doesn't suggest me something like `getClass()` or similar

Comment: actually `getClass()` translates to `::class.java` in Kotlin... but you probably can do all what you want using `::class` instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that `T` itself is not a nullable type, i.e. use something like `where T : Any` on the class declaration, e.g.:

```
class ChangeHistoryUtils<T> (originalBean : T, username : String , modifiedBean: T? = null) where T : Any
```

If you do that you can afterwards just access the methods as you did in Java, e.g. if you just want to reuse the code you already have:

```
fun compareBeans(){
  originalBean::class.java.methods // this is actually your originalBean.getClass().getMethods() !
                   // just print the methods for now...
                            .forEach(::println)
}
```

But as you are using Kotlin you may rather want to use the Kotlin approach then, e.g. just showing the properties, or similar:

```
originalBean::class.memberProperties
             // again just printing them:
                       .forEach(::println)
```

You then need to add `kotlin-reflect` as dependency. You may also want to check the [Kotlin reference regarding reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html).